# Windows Server 2003 SNMP Disk I/O OID's

Tags: windows-server-2003, monitoring, snmp, oid

It's been about few years since I went near SNMP and I now need to capture some metrics from Windows Servers via SNMP.

The last time I did something like this I used iReasoning's MIB Browser to discover some APC networked power outlets OID's.

I vaguely remember having to load a MIB file for the APC's into the MIB browser and seeing the OID's for various metrics.

What MIB file(s) do I need to load to discover the OID's for Windows Server 2003 and 2008 disk metrics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst there are some metrics available under the SNMP tree described by [sysadmin1138](https://serverfault.com/questions/271284/windows-server-2003-snmp-disk-i-o-oids/271290#271290), lots of performance stats aren't available out of the box.

It seems you either have to build your own MIB's from Performance Monitor counters:

> [PERF2MIB.EXE: Performance Monitor MIB Builder Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723464.aspx#XSLTsection130121120120)

Or use a third party SNMP extensions such as SNMP Informant which will expose these metrics:

> [SNMP Informant](http://www.snmp-informant.com/products.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The top of the Windows disk SNMP tree is `.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1`, also known as ".iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.host.hrStorage.hrStorageTable" When I built an SNMP script to grab these kinds of metrics, it was pretty obvious which sub-OIDs belonged to cluster size, allocated space, free space, and volume name.

The one gotcha to be aware of is that Windows does *not* present directory-mounted volumes this way. So if you have a volume mounted to "F:\Backups", you'll see "F:\" in the list, but not "F:\Backups". The only way I found to grab that data was to delve into WMI.

Comment: Ah ha...I was looking under the `private.enterprises....` subtree. Will have a poke around and see what I can find.

Comment: there are *some* metrics but sadly not the ones I'm after. Seems you have to do your own legwork or use a 3rd party SNMP plugin such as SNMP Informant. I've added my own answer to expand on this. Fortunately the stats I'm after are in their free plugin.